# Java Wrapper for Mailchimp API v3.0

Tags: java, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I just started working with the Mailchimp API. So far I have configured the open authentication using `Node.js` and `Angular.js`. I want to implement an export of customers (First name, Last name and Email) from my app to a Mailchimp list. I want to do this in a `Java` worker, so I started looking for a Mailchimp API wrapper for `Java`. So far I have managed to find [ecwid-mailchimp](https://github.com/Ecwid/ecwid-mailchimp) wrapper, but it is for Mailchimp API v2.0 and it looks like the project is dead.

Is there an active implementation of a `Java` wrapper for Mailchimp API v3.0?

It does not seem a good idea to use the old API (v2.0) and a dead implementation in a new project.

The alternative is to do the implementation by myself, but it is a waste of time if someone has already done it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of searching I found [this project on github](https://github.com/micheal-swiggs/mailchimp-java). It is incomplete, but I created a pull request with the OAuth and am currently working on batches.

Answer (score 6):

[MaleOrang](https://github.com/Ecwid/maleorang) is a new Java Wrapper for Mailchimp API v3.0. It is a replacement for [ecwid-mailchimp](https://github.com/Ecwid/ecwid-mailchimp) from the same vendor.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is no existing Java wrapper, but it shouldn't be too hard to do yourself. You'll want to look into the [API v3 batch operations](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/how-to-use-batch-operations/) docs to make this as easy on yourself as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Found one more Java wrapper library, relatively fresh, [bananaj](https://github.com/banana-j/bananaj). At least I've found those API methods that were needed for me, but were missing in libraries from previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

bananaj is amazing library  I forked already  or another way is  calling the rest API https://mailchimp.com/developer/api/marketing/automation-email-queue/ , I was testing using postman and Java http library.